# Reposition animated rigid body

Tags: keyframes, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I made a simple animation of food falling from a bag to a bowl, but this animation starts at frame 0 and I need it to start at 2800.

How can I move it?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you could either recalculate the physics so that they begin from frame 2800 (*Scene panel > Cache > Simulation Start*):

[image]

Or go into the *Object panel > Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes*,it will create a series of keyframes that you'll be able to move:

[image]